# sed decodes html encoding. Need explanation how

Tags: linux, web, sed, character, decoding

Following sed expression decodes HTML URL Encoding (exactly as required):
sed 's/%/\x/g'
HTML encoding reference can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

However, I can't get how it works. Regex seems to say: find "%" and replace it by "\x" in the string, but it does much more then that. Why does it do decoding here ?

```
Example:
$ echo "This%20%2C%20character%20is%20comma" | echo -e "$(sed 's/%/\\x/g')"
This , character is comma
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is changing every `%` to `\x` so `sed 's/%/\\x/g'` changes `%2C` to `\x2C`, for example, and then `echo -e "\x2C"` decodes that hex escape sequence to a literal `,` for printing.

That approach will fail when you want to print a literal `%` char as part of your string. You can make it a little more robust with `sed -r 's/%([[:xdigit:]]{2})/\\x\1/g'` but it may not be worth the added complexity for the few cases where it will stop a false match from occurring.

FWIW with GNU awk you can do:

```
echo "This%20%2C%20character%20is%20comma" |
awk -niord '{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/%(..)(.*)/,a) ) {
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) chr("0x"a[1])
        tail = a[2]
    }
    print head tail
}'
This , character is comma
```

Lengthier than the sed+echo version but easier to enhance if you want to do more with the string.

Comment: Thank you, Ed, for help and sharing ideas.